# can I access a remote mysql server/db from a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, database-connection

Is it possible to connect to a remote instance of mysql server from a stored procedure using sql statements, for select and insert access?

Ideally, it would be something like (pseudo-code):

```
connect to remotedb@remotehost
select field1 from remotedb.table1 where ...
```

I guess I can develop a user-defined function in C/C++ that does it by ODBC. I'd prefer a native syntax if possible, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Using [Federated tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html) feature.