# Connect to remote host from within MySql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, remote-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [can I access a remote mysql server/db from a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323225/can-i-access-a-remote-mysql-server-db-from-a-stored-procedure)

I'm a bit new to MySQL. I want to create a stored routine that accepts a parameter and returns a dataset to a Read-Only user.

Within the stored routine, however, I want to establish a new connection (using different credentials) to a remote MySQL host and read the required values based on the input parameter.

I imagine it would go like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procReturnsData(parameter1)
BEGIN
     <connect to remote MySQL server using new credentials>
     <Select col1, col2 from remoteServer.table1 Where col3 = parameter1 >
     <close connection>
END
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323225/can-i-access-a-remote-mysql-server-db-from-a-stored-procedure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [federated tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html), you can create a remote table.

Unfortunately, I don't think it works with SSH without creating a tunnel at the OS level first.

Comment: This appears to be the preferred way.