# How to access another mysql server from stored procedure?

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [can I access a remote mysql server/db from a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323225/can-i-access-a-remote-mysql-server-db-from-a-stored-procedure)

Is it possible to access another mysql server from stored procedure?

Comment: Perhaps you'll find an answer to your question in this [topic](http://database.ittoolbox.com/documents/connecting-to-and-accessing-a-sql-server-database-on-another-server-18751).

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL access tables from different servers
from a single connection is federated tables:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html
Once you do that, it like access to a local table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a [UDF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-function-udf.html) which is user-defined function. You only should create and install this function into MySQL. It may be a little bit difficult, but you could try it.

And a simple way to access tables is to use federated engine (as Rena Sun suggested), was answered here - [MySQL — Joins Between Databases On Different Servers Using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832787/mysql-joins-between-databases-on-different-servers-using-python/5832973#5832973).